# Custom IMG attribute retrieval

Tags: jquery

I'm having trouble retrieving custom attributes from images.

```
<img src="" data-type="bg" />
```

I'm retrieving it like this:

```
 initFeaturedImages : function () {
        $('.story-page').each(function () {
            var $fImg = $(this).find('.right-side img');
            if ($fImg.length) {
                var src = $fImg[0].src;
                var type = $fImg[0].data('type'); 
                $($fImg[0]).hide();

                var $bg = $fImg.parents('.story-page').find('.left-side');


                if (type) {
                    $bg.css('background-image','url('+ src +')');
                }
                else {
                    $bg.append('<figure><img src="'+src+'" /></figure>'); 
                }
            }
        });
    },
```

And it throws error:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'o[0].data("type")')
```

What might be the problem? Knowing that I've tried with $fImg[0].attr('data-type') and the same error is thrown on title attribute also.

Comment: It worked ! Thanks.  Could you please explain why? Cause for the image source it worked: `var src = $fImg[0].src` ?

Comment: whenever you get this type of issue add debbuger and type object name [$fImg] in Console you will get actual error or by add watch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$fImg[0]` is javascript object which has no `.data()` method.You should use:

```
 $fImg.data('type');
```

if you have multiple images then to get all:

```
  $fImg.each(function(){
     alert($(this).data('type'));
  });
```